# audio/android/cutils/bitops.h:65:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ffs'

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I ndk-build my project for "APP_ABI := X86" , with cocos2d-x 3.14.1, but getting the error log:

cocos2d/cocos/audio/android/../../audio/android/cutils/bitops.h:65:15: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ffs'

Do you saw it and how to fix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/439

Update to the latest NDK and it should work.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks a lot !